# What are the range of Fourier coefficients such that the resultant function is positive and bounded?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, bounded-variation

Consider some yet-to-be-determined, periodic, real-valued function, $f(x)$ (where $x \in [-L,L]$), defined in terms of the first $2M + 1$ Fourier coefficients, i.e. $$f(x) = \sum_{n = -M}^M c_n e^{-i\frac{n \pi x}{L}},$$
where $2L$ is the period of the function. Given that $0 \leq f(x) \leq k$ over the entire range, what are the restrictions on the possible values that the coefficients can take (e.g. in terms of k, or recursively?). Yes, this is not the full Fourier series, but rather a finite approximation to it where $M$ can become arbitrarily large. Put differently, how do we constrain the values of these Fourier coefficients such that the resultant function is bounded and positive?

So far, I know that we require the $c_0$ term to be at least as large as the sum of the other terms in the sum, however I'm not sure this keeps the function bounded below $k$. Furthermore, each coefficient need not be real valued (except for $c_0$), only that $c_n = c_{-n}^*$ such that the resultant function is real valued. Therefore, I imagine the answer could be that each coefficient will be constrained to be in some circle around the origin of the Argand plane of radius $r_n$ for each coefficient $c_n$. But I'm not sure, and especially not sure how to find this radius!

Bonus: same question but with $\lim(M \rightarrow \infty).$

Comment: "as large as the sum of the $\color{red}{\text{absolute values}}$ of the other terms in the sum". Indeed the $c_n$ are complex.

Comment: Have a look at the first theorems cited in [this publication](http://www.math.bas.bg/serdica/1976/1976-138-142.pdf). The original article establishing them is behind a paywall.

Comment: Feijer Riesz theorem gives equivalent conditions for a trigonometric polynomial to be nonnegative (namely iff it is the square modulus of a regular polynomial which can be taken uniquely up to constants when all its roots are arranged to be outside the open unit disc), so one has expressions for its coefficients that can be used to deduce stuff; however $1+\cos nx$ is nonnegative for all $n$ so not sure one can really say much in general beyond $c_0>0, c_0 \ge |c_k|$; see https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r-Riesz_theorem

Comment: In my head, the "thought experiment" behind this is to imagine that a Random Number Generator is generating complex numbers of the form $c_n = r_n e^{i \theta_n}$ satisfying $c_n = c_n^*$. It is clear to me that the imaginary part being conjugate means theta doesn't really matter so much, but that the $r_n$ do. Given $c_0 \geq \sum_{n = -m, n \neq 0}^M r_n$, surely its a question of trying to fix the $r_n$ such that this condition is satisfied. i.e. distributing the $k/2$ "amount" of positivity across the coefficients such that the overall function is bounded by $k$.

Comment: And therefore, using the Feijer-Riesz theorem, to ensure the function is bounded, then we would need to impose additional constraints of the $a_j$ coefficients in the polynomial from the link you provided. I can see how this theorem ensures positivity, just not sure whether it is sufficient to also guarantee the resulting function still satisfies $f(x) \leq k$.

Answer (score -1):

$f$ is $2L$-periodic, and we see by the orthogonality relation,
$$
c_n = \frac{1}{2L}\int_{-L}^L f(x)e^{-in\pi x/L} dx.
$$
Now we can use the bound $0 \leq f(x) \leq k$ to see
$$
|c_n| = \left|\frac{1}{2L}\int_{-L}^L f(x)e^{-in\pi x/L} dx\right| \leq \frac{1}{2L}\int_{-L}^L \left|f(x)e^{-in\pi x/L}\right|dx = \frac{1}{2L}\int_{-L}^L |f(x)| dx \leq \frac{1}{2L}\int_{-L}^L kdx = k.
$$
Hence we have the condition
$$
|c_n| \leq k \text{ for all } n \in \{-M, -M+1, \cdots, M-1, M\}.
$$
I think this works in the infinite case too, but some care might be needed due to the infinite sum.

Comment: This is a necessary condition only.

Comment: actually this doesn't use nonnegativity anywhere, so it's valid for any bounded $f$; if $f$ is nonnegative one can easily shows that $|c_0| \ge |c_k|$ and since by Parseval one has that $\sum |a_k|^2 \le k^2$ this immediately imply much stronger bounds on $|c-1|,..|c_n|$

Comment: I think this condition is too loose, because imagine that $c_n = k \forall n$, then from the question itself, we know that the $c_0$ term is at least as large as this. At x = 0, this would make the function bigger than $k$, its upper bound...